# How to reverse a shape in Keras for LSTM input

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

I have my input state with shape = (84,84,4)

```
state = Input(shape=(84,84,4), dtype="float")
```

It's stacked sequence of continuous frames.

I want to pass this state to the keras model as input,
firstly - to TimeDistributed layers
and then - to LSTM

as I understand, time step is the **first** dimension
and I need to **reshape** my state appropriately to

```
shape=(4, 84, 84)
```

and holds the frames in their own size and topology

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
state_t=tf.transpose(state,[2,1,0])
```

Is this what you are looking for ?
(or [2,0,1] that depends on what you wanna do...)